# Python matplotlib animated candlestick clearing and redeploying new data as standard live stock chart

Tags: python-2.7, animation, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I have modified some existing source from this site to update a single candle stick with dynamic resizing. The code below does this for going up but not going down (a problem to clear and redraw the canvas with chart and new data for one already painted candlestick). Is there a way to clear candlesticks and repaint them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc


# make plot interactive in order to update
#plt.ion()

class Chart3(object):
    def __init__(self, data, maxt=10):
        self.maxt = maxt
        self.data = data
        self.result = data[:self.maxt]

        # Parse the data columns
        self.tdata = [r[0] for r in self.result]
        self.sdata = [r[4] for r in self.result]
        self.mdata = [r[3] for r in self.result]

        # Initialize plot frame
        xfmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
        self.ax.xaxis_date()
        plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='center')
        self.animate()

    def plot(self):
        if len(self.tdata) > self.maxt:  # roll the arrays
            self.tdata = self.tdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.sdata = self.sdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.mdata = self.mdata[-self.maxt:]
            self.result = self.result[-self.maxt:]

        # Plot the next set of line data
        ##line_min = Line2D(self.tdata, self.sdata, color='r')
        ##self.ax.add_line(line_min)
        ##line_max = Line2D(self.tdata, self.mdata, color='g')
        ##self.ax.add_line(line_max)

        # Plot the next set of candlestick data
        #plt.gcf().clear()
        #self.ax.clear()
        candlestick_ohlc(self.ax, self.result, width=50 / 86400.0,  colorup='g', colordown='r')
        plt.clear()
        #fig.canvas.update()
        fig.canvas.draw()

        # Update the x-axis time date and limits
        if len(self.tdata) > 1:
            self.ax.set_xlim(self.tdata[0], self.tdata[-1])

        # Update the y-axis limits
        self.ax.set_ylim(min(self.sdata) * 0.99, max(self.mdata) * 1.01)
        ##plt.draw()

    def update_prices(self, cnt):
        """
        adds a data point from data to result list for plotting
        @return:
        """
        results = self.data[self.maxt + cnt]  # add another point of data
        t = (results[0])
        if self.tdata[-1] != t:
            trade = results
            self.result.append([t, trade[1], trade[2], trade[3], trade[4], trade[5], trade[6]])
            self.tdata.append(self.result[-1][0])
            self.sdata.append(self.result[-1][4])
            self.mdata.append(self.result[-1][3])
        else:
            trade = results
            self.result.append([t, trade[1], trade[2], trade[3], trade[4], trade[5], trade[6]])
            # self.tdata.append(self.result[-1][0])
            self.sdata.append(self.result[-1][4])
            self.mdata.append(self.result[-1][3])

    def update_plot(self, i):
        try:
            self.update_prices(cnt=i)
            self.plot()
        except:
            pass

    def animate(self):
        # With try ... except in update_plot()
        # anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=self.fig, func=self.update_plot, interval=1000)

        # Without try ... except in update_plot()
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=self.fig, func=self.update_plot, interval=1000,
                                       frames=len(self.data)-self.maxt, repeat=False)
        # plt.autoscale(False)

        #f = plt.figure()
        #f.show()
        plt.show()
        plt.gcf().clear() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testData = [
        [735265.79166666663, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
        [735265.79305555555, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
        [735265.79236111115, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 21.901, 0],
        [735265.79374999995, 21.9, 21.901, 21.901, 21.9, 21.9005, 11.65],
        [735265.79444444447, 21.901, 21.939, 21.939, 21.901, 21.91525, 23.23606],
        [735265.79513888888, 21.94, 21.95, 21.9703, 21.94, 21.953781250000002, 172.91374199999998],
        [735265.79583333328, 21.96, 21.99, 21.99, 21.96, 21.973333333333336, 142.974981],
        [735265.7965277778, 21.995, 21.995, 21.997, 21.995, 21.995533333333338, 36.541180000000004],
        [735265.7972222222, 21.9703, 21.995, 22.0, 21.9703, 21.993162500000004, 18.305711],
        [735265.79791666672, 21.9999, 21.86, 22.0, 21.86, 21.93492, 103.2468273],
        [735265.79861111112, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 21.9045, 2.43879],
        [735265.79930555553, 21.929, 21.861, 21.99, 21.86, 21.92566666666666, 2.838343],
        [735265.80000000005, 21.9241, 21.899, 21.9241, 21.899, 21.907366666666665, 10.0],
        [735265.80069444445, 21.861, 21.86, 21.861, 21.86, 21.860888888888887, 111.367172],
        [735265.80138888885, 21.86, 21.861, 21.861, 21.86, 21.8604, 78.36582],
        [735265.80208333337, 21.861, 21.862, 21.862, 21.859, 21.860483333333335, 112.842532],
        [735265.80277777778, 21.862, 21.863, 21.88, 21.862, 21.8694, 83.64361899999999],
        [735265.80347222218, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 21.88, 7.46027],
        [735265.8041666667, 21.88, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.88, 21.9104, 7.06897],
        [735265.8048611111, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 0.339032],
        [735265.8055555555, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 21.9256, 2.024438],
        [735265.80625000002, 21.88, 21.88, 21.881, 21.88, 21.880249999999997, 25.00003],
        [735265.80694444443, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 0],
        [735265.80763888895, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 21.92, 0],
        [735265.80833333335, 21.91, 21.92, 21.92, 21.91, 21.915, 80.0],
        [735265.80902777775, 21.881, 21.92, 21.92, 21.881, 21.907, 43.913890200000004],
        [735265.80972222227, 21.914, 22.0, 22.0, 21.914, 21.973115625, 368.000066],
        [735265.81041666667, 21.93, 21.99, 21.79, 21.83, 21.43, 0],
        [735265.81111111108, 21.83, 22.13, 21.8, 22.0, 21.9225, 15.475088999999999],
        [735265.81180555548, 22.0, 22.1, 21.8, 21.84, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81249999988, 21.84, 22.2, 21.8, 22.15, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81319444428, 22.15, 22.2, 21.95, 22.16, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81319444428, 22.15, 22.2, 21.95, 22.17, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81319444428, 22.15, 22.2, 21.95, 22.18, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81319444428, 22.15, 22.2, 21.95, 22.2, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81319444428, 22.15, 22.2, 21.95, 22.18, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81319444428, 22.15, 22.2, 21.95, 22.17, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81319444428, 22.15, 22.2, 21.95, 22.16, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81388888868, 22.2, 22.2, 21.8, 21.8, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81388888868, 22.2, 22.2, 21.8, 21.85, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81388888868, 22.2, 22.2, 21.8, 21.86, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81388888868, 22.2, 22.2, 21.8, 21.87, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
        [735265.81388888868, 22.2, 22.2, 21.8, 21.88, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996],
#        [735265.8118055556, 22.0, 22.0, 21.8, 21.84, 21.97401, 56.620048589999996]
    ]
# open, high, low, close

    chart = Chart3(data=testData)
```

Comment: I was working backward with the test data, so stream set-up to test dynamically updating one candlestick reserved in this dataset as the last two candles at the end of running the program. FYI!